# In the induced fit model for enzyme action, does the enzyme active site change slightly after products form?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

The reason why I am asking is because I am looking at a past paper and they highlight that it does. I have attached it below. Could you explain why this is the case.

[image]

[image]

I am just looking for a quick overview of why this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now that they are highlighting how during the transition state the enzyme was induced to change shape, but once products formed and left active site, there was further changing of shape of the enzyme active site so it could return back to its original shape - therefore it could be reused again, as in line with the role of an enzyme/ catalyst.